# Solve differential equation .

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have to solve the differential equation:

$$(x^3+y^2+2) {\rm d}x + 2y \,{\rm d}y =0 $$

I tried a lot but not able to do anything

Comment: "I tried a lot" like what specifically?

Comment: put $z=y^2$ note that $dz=2ydy$

Answer (score 2):

With $z=y^2$, the equation becomes

$$z'+z=-x^3-2.$$

without RHS, we obtain

$$z_h=Ce^{-x}.$$

to get a particular solution $z_p=C(x)e^{-x}$, we solve

$$C'(x)=(-2-x^3)e^x.$$

multiple by parts integration yields to

$C(x)=(-2-x^3+3(x^2-2(x-1)))e^x$,

which gives

$$z=z_p+z_h$$

$=-x^3+3x^2-6x+4+Ce^{-x}=y^2$